Algorithm used by VASP for lm decomposition while writing the PROCAR file
I suppose that VASP defines the coordinate system for a given calculation from the POSCAR file. Now when I am using the LORBIT = 11 tag, it writes $\textit{lm}$ decomposed orbital projections for each band and each K-point. I initially assumed that lobes of, say a localized $d_{xy}$ orbital would be in the xy plane according to the initial defined coordinate system. However, when plotting the projected charge density, I find the coordinate system is actually rotated and the $d_{xy}$ orbital is in a plane 45 degrees tilted from my initial definition in POSCAR.
Is this related to the algorithm used by VASP for $\textit{lm}$ decomposition? Or is the inherent coordinate system for orbitals itself a system-specific characteristic that VASP determines? Does it guarantee that if I give lattice coordinates differently for all atoms in my POSCAR, then also orbitals retain their identity?
